# Duplicate symbol in admob static library

Tags: iphone, admob, static-libraries, gdata, duplicate-symbol

In my application i am using libGoogleAdMobAds.a and libGDataTouchStaticLib.a for ads and video sharing on YouTube but it shows the duplicate symbols for architecture i386 for libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(SBJSON.o)

How can i avoid this error in my app?

Comment: There may be two files in the same name. Check that..