# duplicate symbol

Tags: ios

I have two framework(A.framework and B.framework).
B.framework link with A.framework, and I have a project,the project link With A and B,then link error :duplicate symbol

how to solve the problem? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The two frameworks probably define a class or function with the same name. If the libraries are yours, you should rename your symbols using prefixes as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html). If not, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558394/how-can-i-isolate-third-parties-c-c-objc-libraries-symbols-from-each-other) — you probably won't be able to work around this without changing the libraries.